# View Does Not Change After Model Update

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services

I'm working on a football project that is giving me issues when I update a service model. I have two components (AvailablePlayers and SelectedPlayers) and two services (AvailablePlayersService and SelectedPlayersService).

The available players component lists all available players in which a user can build their custom team. (think Fantasy Football) The selected players component lists all the players the user selected from the available players. Both the services have only a hard-coded model so I can test with.

My problem is when I click on the add button in the available players component to add to the SelectedPlayersService model I expect the view in the selected players component to update, but nothing happens. My lists are being populated correctly so I know the services are injected into the components properly.

My guess is I need to watch the model some how, but I'm not sure if Angular 2 has that ability.

**available-players.component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-available-players',
    templateUrl: './available-players.component.html',
    providers: [AvailablePlayersService, SelectedPlayersService]
})

export class AvailablePlayersComponent {
    public _availablePlayers;
    public _selectedPlayers;

    selectPlayer = (data) => {
        _selectedPlayers.addSelectedPlayer(data); // using running backs for testing AND I feel this is the problem
    }

    constructor(availablePlayers:AvailablePlayersService, selectedPlayers:SelectedPlayersService) {
        this._availablePlayers = availablePlayers.getAvailablePlayers(); // get the available players model
        this._selectedPlayers = selectedPlayers._selectedPlayersModel; // get the selected players model so I can add players to it
    }
}
```

**available-players.component html**

```
<div class="player-card" *ngFor="let player of _availablePlayers; let i = index">
    <div class="playa-data">
        <span class="player-name">{{ player.name }}</span>
        <i class="fa fa-plus" (click)="selectPlayer(i, player);$event.stopPropagation()"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

**selected-players.service**

```
@Injectable()
export class SelectedPlayersService {

    public _selectedPlayersModel;

    public addSelectedPlayer = (data) => {
        this._selectedPlayersModel.runningBacks.push(data);
    }

    constructor() {
        this._selectedPlayersModel = [
            runningBacks: [{
                id: 2, 
                imageUrl: '423.png', 
                name: 'Player Bob', 
                position: 'RB',
            }],
        ];
    };
}
```

**selected-players.component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-selected-players',
    templateUrl: './selected-players.component.html',
    providers: [SelectedPlayersService]
})

export class SelectedPlayersComponent {
    private _selectedPlayers;

    constructor(private selectedPlayers: SelectedPlayersService) {
        this._selectedPlayers = selectedPlayers._selectedPlayersModel;
    }
}
```

**selected-players.component html**

```
<div class="position-card">
    <span>Running Backs</span>
    <div *ngFor="let player of _selectedPlayers.runningBacks">
        <span class="player-name">{{ player.name }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are injecting the providers in both of the Components decorators. This will give you two different copies, which is not what you want. You should inject the services only once, somewhere higher in the tree, for example in your AppComponent, if you have one.

Also, your services should expose their data as `Observables`. This way you can listen for changes in the data.

Like so:

```
@Injectable()
export class SelectedPlayersService {

    private _selectedPlayers;
    public selectedPlayers$; //behaviour subject observable

    public addSelectedPlayer = (data) => {
        this._selectedPlayers.runningBacks.push(data);
        this.selectedPlayers$.next(
            Object.assign({}, this._selectedPlayers)
        );
    }

    constructor() {
        this._selectedPlayers = {
            runningBacks: [{
                id: 2, 
                imageUrl: '423.png', 
                name: 'Player Bob', 
                position: 'RB',
            }],
        };
        this.selectedPlayers$ = new BehaviourSubject(
            Object.assign({}, this._selectedPlayers)
        );
    };
}
```

And then your components can subscribe like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-selected-players',
    templateUrl: './selected-players.component.html',
    providers: [SelectedPlayersService]
})
export class SelectedPlayersComponent {
    private _selectedPlayers;

    constructor(private selectedPlayers: SelectedPlayersService) {
        this.selectedPlayers.selectedPlayers$.subscribe(
            players => this._selectedPlayer = players
        );
    }
}
```

Of course, you would have to import BehaviourSubject, like `import { BehaviourSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviourSubject';`

Comment: Very cool, never would of thought to inject it higher up like in the app.component. I'm going to implement it now and I'll get back. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Quick question, if I inject `SelectedPlayersService` in my `app.component` do I still need to inject it into `available-players.component` and `selected-player.component`?

Comment: Just implemented your suggestions and I can't seem to get it. I get no errors and when I `console.log()` the selectedPlayers I can see the array has been pushed. The view just isn't updating when a selected player is added.

Comment: Is the subscription callback firing? And did you remove the service injections everywhere except in the app component?